# Perform left_join between df1 and df2 where df2 gives a range for the joining variable in df1

Tags: r, join, dplyr, merge, left-join

I am trying to merge two data frames.

`df1` contains company level data with columns `company_name` and `industry_code`. Say `df1` looks like this:

| company_name | industry_code |
| --- | --- |
| A | 33 |
| B | 43 |
| C | 56 |
| D | 88 |

`df2` contains `industry_name`, `min_code`, `max_code`. Say `df2` looks like this:

| industry_name | min_code | max_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Smoke | 10 | 19 |
| Food | 20 | 39 |
| Care | 40 | 69 |
| Manufacturing | 70 | 99 |

I want to merge the `df2` industry data to `df1` company data. Such that, post-merge, the data looks like this:

| company_name | industry_code | industry_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 33 | Food |
| B | 43 | Care |
| C | 56 | Care |
| D | 88 | Manufacturing |

Please see below my failed attempts:

```
# first attempt
df1 %>%
left_join(df2, by = c("industry_code" = "min_code"))

# second attempt
df1 %>%
mutate(industry_name = ifelse(between(industry_code, df2$min_code, df2$max_code), df2$industry_name, NA)
```

Comment: df1 %>% left_join(df2, join_by(between(industry_code, min_code, max_code)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jon has already said, the simplest answer using dplyr is to use `join_by()`:

```
df1 |>
  left_join(df2, join_by(between(industry_code, min_code, max_code))) |>
  select(-min_code, -max_code)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  company_name industry_code industry_name
  <chr>                <dbl> <chr>        
1 A                       33 Food         
2 B                       43 Care         
3 C                       56 Care         
4 D                       88 Manufacturing
```

The issue with the first attempt, is, (as I'm sure you're already aware), the industry codes don't match the min codes, so you get NAs.

The issue with the second attempt can be made clearer if you play around with it a bit:

```
between(c(88, 88, 88, 88), df2$min_code, df2$max_code) # [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

between(c(33, 33, 33, 33), df2$min_code, df2$max_code) # [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

between(c(33, 33, 33, 33, 33), df2$min_code, df2$max_code) 
# Error in between(c(33, 33, 33, 33, 33), df2$min_code, df2$max_code) : 
#  Incompatible vector lengths: length(x)==5 length(lower)==4 length(upper)==4. Each should be either length 1 or the length of the longest.
```

The code isn't checking each industry code against every min and max value, it's checking the first industry code against the first min and the first max, and so on.

If you still wanted to use this approach, looping over industry_name with map_chr() works. Also, there are no gaps in your sample data, so if that's also the case with your real data, you could potentially use base R's `findInterval()` e.g. `df2$industry_name[findInterval(df1$industry_code, df2$min_code)]`.

Answer (score 0):

**data.table**

```r
library(data.table)

df2 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
     industry_name = c("Smoke", "Food", "Care", "Manufacturing"),
          min_code = c(10L, 20L, 40L, 70L),
          max_code = c(19L, 39L, 69L, 99L)
)


df1 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
      company_name = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
     industry_code = c(33L, 43L, 56L, 88L)
)

setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

df2[df1, list(company_name, industry_code, industry_name), on = list(max_code >= industry_code, min_code <= industry_code)]
#>    company_name industry_code industry_name
#> 1:            A            33          Food
#> 2:            B            43          Care
#> 3:            C            56          Care
#> 4:            D            88 Manufacturing
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>